# "such a lot of friends"

Tags: word-choice, difference

What's up with that phrase "**such a lot of** friends", "**such a lot** of money" etc
First of all, I've never heard it before, not in 30 years. Second of all, why isn't it "**so** a lot of friends" (sounds strange to me too, but makes more sense), since just like "**much**" (so much money), "**a lot**" is an *adverb*.. Please help me understand it.

Comment: You have opened Pandora's box. See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284736/is-the-of-in-a-lot-of-a-preposition     https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lot_1

Comment: I think the meanings of those phrases depend on the entire sentence they were a part of.

Comment: _Much_ is a quantifier, and is treated as scalar, so you can have _so much_, _how much_, _as much as_, _A lot_ is syntactically a noun phrase, so it cannot take those modifiers, but it can take _such_. You're right that _a lot_ can be an adverb, but it isn't here.

Answer (score 1):

"Such" can be a determiner like "so", but we use them differently, for example:

- *So many* people!
- *Such a lot of* people!

You'll notice in these two idiomatic phrases that "*so*" is used with the *plural noun* "people", whereas "*such*" is used with the singular collective noun "a lot". We would never say "such many" or "so a lot of", so really the choice of "such" and "so" is directly related to the noun or pronoun it precedes.

However, "so" can be used to emphasise an adjective, so you could easily rearrange a sentence to use either:

- That is such a great film!
- That film is so great!

In the first example, "such" is operating on the noun phrase "great film"; in the second example "so" is operating on the adjective "great" alone.

Comment: You say "so" is used with plural noun "people", I mean so is "such" in your examples.